# How can I return back this feature in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a problem in VS Code. When I used it before I could always see description about
any PHP function(like what this function is doing and examples) in 'autocomplete bar'. But it disappeared recently. I think that the reason
why this happens is because I accidentally deleted one of the PHP extenstions, but I am not sure.
Please help me I really liked this feature.

Comment: You mean this part? the red out line or the whole thing? https://i.imgur.com/OMwrGSW.png

Comment: Please add screenshots to show what feature you are missing exactly

Comment: I have a screenshot here https://imgur.com/TQEqZYd. In a red field I had a information about a function but now it is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to press `Ctrl+Space` Again on it to toggle that box.

There is no setting for it in VSCode to keep it on always but if you toggle it once, it will stay until you turn it off again.

[image: Toggle Intellisense Description]

Comment: I tried it and it worked!!!!. Thank you very much:)

Comment: yw! Also add the screenshot you posted to your question for future reference.